# SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date: "9-Jul" when using parse method

Tags: java, date, datetime, apache-poi, simpledateformat

I wanted to use `SimpleDateFormat.parse` method to set the date:

```
 private static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
 ...
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  calendar.setTime(fmt.parse("9-Jul"));
  calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "9-Jul"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at BusinessPlan.main(BusinessPlan.java:116)
```

The code comes from Apache sample site and it is published with [this bug](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/BusinessPlan.java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

works fine for me

try setting `Locale`

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM", Locale.US);
```

Comment: How to set Locale and where I should do it.

Comment: sorry missed it in earlier edit, please check update in answer

Answer (score 3):

I think because you use "dd" you'd have to use 09 instead of 9.

Comment: Good point, but did not help. It's probably problem with localization.